# mysqli_query activates automatically inside function?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

For whatever reason my database updates as if the function ran, but it never echod anything. When I reload the page it automatically sets the name to "John", but I never clicked the button.

```
    <?php
    function a(){
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "example", "example", "example");
      $sql = "UPDATE User SET name = 'John' WHERE name = '$username'";

      mysqli_query($con, $sql);

      //test to see if function fires:
      echo "function executed";
    }
    ?>
```

Here is my html / javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function b(){
      document.write("<?php a(); ?>");

      //test if javascript function executes:
      alert("function b() executed");
    }
    </script>

    <button onclick="b()">Click me!</button>
```

I had to do the javascript because my entire page is a form (for the purpose of a single save button) and you can`t directly have a button execute a php function.

I am just really confused why it doesn't echo, but it does update my database when I reload the page, please help.

Comment: where is the php located on your page?

Comment: That is not going to work as you expect. The PHP script will not be executed (compiled and run). You might want to have a look at [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Answer (score 1):

of course you will update the database every time you load the page because of this line

```
document.write("<?php a(); ?>");
```

every time you load the page you are calling `a()` which updates the database

the reason of why function `a` is not echoing `"function executed"`, is it **DOES** but you don't see it on the page because it is echoed in it's line. I'm sure you will see it in the page source.

When the PHP parser parse your script it will produce and respond with this

```
document.write("function executed");
```

Comment: Have a closer look. The PHP code will not run when the user calls the Javascript function `b()` by clicking on the `button`.

Comment: @Tigger, yes of course the php function will not be executed when the user clicks on the button!  . I mean the php function will be executed every time the parser will try to parse this line `<?php a(); ?>` not when the button is clicked

Comment: What confused me is that document.write("<?php a(); ?>") is activated even though it's inside of a function

Comment: @ArvidvandenHoogen do you mean inside a JavaScript function ? if so, what is confusing about that? when you write`<?php` inside your document that means you want the PHP parser to interpret this block of code and produce dynamic content . Sure you can write JavaScript code with PHP, I'm not doing this though, I'm just trying to explain this expected behavior to you, and if you want to update when you click the button, then you go with the AJAX solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have very little understanding of javascript and have only heard of ajax a couple of times before. I was confused because as far as I knew, code in a function was only called upon when the function was called. With this idea in mind I wrote the code above. Thanks for explaining :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to call the PHP script by clicking on the `button`. Something like the following will work.

Do *not* include the PHP script on your page and the mysql will only be called after clicking the `button`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax(url) {
    var http = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (! http) {
        // old browser or terminal maybe?
        return false;
    }
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((http.readyState == 4) && (http.status == 200)) {
            // do stuff with the html/json/data returned
            // this alert will trigger once the PHP is run.
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.open('GET',url,true);
    http.send(null);
}

function b(){
    // call the code on PHP script to run.
    ajax("/path/to/your/php");
    //test if javascript function executes:
    // this alert should fire first.
    alert("function b() executed");
}
</script>

<button onclick="b()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Will this script just run an entire php script or should I declare a function? I need to send a few variables to the function, how would I do that with ajax?

Comment: Read the linked page. You could pass a form object, then use those variables to work out what to do.